# Run the script file after 5 or 10 min after restarting the system

Tags: cron, scripts

I have created a ruby script file that checks the connection present or not. For example checking port 22 is opened or not.

Firstly I tried with cron job as follows

```
@reboot find ${HOME}/my_app/check_conn.rb
```

But it is executing immediately after starting the system.

Now I have to run this script after 5 or 10 min.

How can I do this. Is there any other way for doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A bad hack: Add `sleep 600;` to the beginning of the command.

Comment: I would never execute from cron itself and always create an executable file in /etc/cronjob; Just put an `at` command inside that file to execute it 5 minutes from now?

Comment: @dan08 did I have to add `sleep 600;` before my cron_job or in my script file?

Comment: @dan08, please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `sleep 600;` to the beginning of your crontab command to make it wait for 600 seconds before proceeding to the next step.

Your new crontab command would look like

`@reboot sleep 600; find ${HOME}/my_app/check_conn.rb`

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it depending on time, but after establishing a network connection. The right place to do it is below:

```
/etc/network/if-up.d
```